# str_replace don't work for some chars

Tags: php, str-replace, arabic, numeric

I wrote below code but it works wrong:

```
$t = "۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹٤٥٦";
$correct = array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","4","5","6");
$wrong = array("٠","١","٢","٣","٤","٥","٦","٧","٨","٩","۴","۵","۶");
echo $t = str_replace($wrong,$correct, $t);
```

and the result isn't right

```
۰۱۲۳456۷۸۹۰۱۲۳456۷۸۹456
```

I search in stack and same questions and it's answers don't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don`t know any about the problem, but you can try this function to implement the idea:

```
//converts the numbers into the persian's number
function persianNum($srting)
{
    $num0="&#1776;";
    $num1="&#1777;";
    $num2="&#1778;";
    $num3="&#1779;";
    $num4="&#1780;";
    $num5="&#1781;";
    $num6="&#1782;";
    $num7="&#1783;";
    $num8="&#1784;";
    $num9="&#1785;";

    $stringtemp="";
    $len=strlen($srting);
    for($sub=0;$sub<$len;$sub++)
    {
         if(substr($srting,$sub,1)=="0")$stringtemp.=$num0;
         elseif(substr($srting,$sub,1)=="1")$stringtemp.=$num1;
         elseif(substr($srting,$sub,1)=="2")$stringtemp.=$num2;
         elseif(substr($srting,$sub,1)=="3")$stringtemp.=$num3;
         elseif(substr($srting,$sub,1)=="4")$stringtemp.=$num4;
         elseif(substr($srting,$sub,1)=="5")$stringtemp.=$num5;
         elseif(substr($srting,$sub,1)=="6")$stringtemp.=$num6;
         elseif(substr($srting,$sub,1)=="7")$stringtemp.=$num7;
         elseif(substr($srting,$sub,1)=="8")$stringtemp.=$num8;
         elseif(substr($srting,$sub,1)=="9")$stringtemp.=$num9;
         else $stringtemp.=substr($srting,$sub,1);
    }
return   $stringtemp;

}
//end convert function
```

Comment: This code is slow. Every if statement it is going to run the `substr()` function, when having a long for-loop and this many `substr` functions, your code will be dramatically slow! It is better to have a switch (http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) if you want to use this method. Which again, is not recommended. I am not going to downvote it though, because it is helpful, but not that great either.

Comment: Yes, you are right! the code is too heavy and slow, but it is the most flexible one in facing a piece of HTML code to replace in.

Comment: I want opposite it, I want to convert persian number to latin, so I change your code to it `if(substr($srting,$sub,2)=="$num8")$stringtemp.=8;` because unicodes get 2 byte

Answer (score 2):

> Use this code:-

```
$t = "۰۱۲۳٤٥٦";
$text = preg_replace(
            array("٠","١","٢","٣","٤","٥","٦",),
            array("0","1","2","3","4","5","6",),
            $t );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try 'mb_str_replace()' function.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php

Answer (score 0):

There is no mb_str_repalce function In PHP. This code converts the characters in the string from Eastern Arabic numerals to Hindu-Arabic numerals:

```
<?php
function arabic_convert($str = ''){
    $str_list = preg_split('//u', $str, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    if( !empty($str_list) ){
        $transform_symbols = array(
            '٠' => '0',
            '١' => '1',
            '٢' => '2',
            '٣' => '3',
            '٤' => '4',
            '٥' => '5',
            '٦' => '6',
            '٧' => '7',
            '٨' => '8',
            '٩' => '9',
        );

        $str_transform = array();

        foreach ($str_list as $str_item){
            if( isset($transform_symbols[$str_item]) ){
                $str_transform[] = $transform_symbols[$str_item];
            }else{
                $str_transform[] = $str_item;
            }
        }

        $str = implode('', $str_transform);
    }

    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Please, explain why this code helps with the problem of the OP.

Comment: There is no mb_str_repalce function In PHP. This code converts the characters in the string from Eastern Arabic numerals to Hindu-Arabic numerals